# Can silicone be used in a led bulb to transfer heat from a led filament (COB) to the glass?

Tags: led, heatsink

I am building my own led filament bulbs, and would like to use silicone to secure a flexible filament in place inside a glass test tube. Assuming that the tube is filled with silicone, would silicone be as good or better at allowing heat from the filament to dissipate to the test tube?

Comment: Have you researched on thermal properties of resins at all?

Comment: ... or of glass, for that matter? It sounds like you need to think this through a little more carefully, starting with figuring out exactly how much heat you need to get rid of.

Comment: Led filament bulbs are designed for a long lifespan using only the air inside the glass to dissipate their low heat output. However, the lifespan would be reduced if heat dissipation is reduced too much. I posed my question to find out if silicone would be as good, better, or worse than the air inside the bulb. I have edited my question to simplify it, and removed a reference to resin. I understand that the thermal properties of silicone can vary depending on its formulation, but have not been able to find much information on how different types of silicone would  perform in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Silicones are probably not suitable due to its thermal insulating properties.

You can however buy transparent polyurethane potting compounds.
For example, the cheapest one I could find: UR5640 (from electrolube)

It specifies a [thermal conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity) of 0.20 W/m.K. Which isn't very high, since any metals will be >1, but not an insulator since those are <0.1.

Pouring it will be complicated, since you **will need to** [evacuate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum) the compound prior to, or after pouring.